# Rails array group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a dynamic array of object result from a database query.

```
USERNAME   choice_indx   legend
USER1        3             4
USER2        0             4
USER3        0             4
USER1        9             2
USER2        9             2
USER3        8             2
USER1        3             1
USER2        9             1
USER3        8             1
```

Query:

```
SELECT survey_answers.anonymous_user_id, survey_answers.choice_index, survey_questions.legend 
  FROM `survey_answers` 
  LEFT JOIN surveys ON surveys.id = survey_answers.survey_id 
  LEFT JOIN survey_questions ON survey_questions.id = survey_answers.survey_question_id 
  WHERE (survey_questions.legend IN (1,2,4)) AND (survey_answers.track_id =2) AND (survey_answers.survey_id =2) AND (surveys.survey_type =2)
```

How can I group this by user and result it like this:

```
final_array = {
  "USER1" => [[3,4],[9,2],[3,1]], 
  "USER2" => [[0,4],[9,2],[9,1]],
  "USER3" => [[0,4],[8,2],[8,1]]
}
```

I've tried using group_by in rails, but the result was not the same from what I want. Can anyone lend me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Please show your query.

Comment: I have updated my question and include the query.

Comment: I'm assuming that Jordan's answer would work, but for those of us who are not so able to see the answers in our head, can you post a sample of the actually output of your query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `objects` is an Enumerable of ActiveModel objects with `anonymous_user_id`, `choice_index`, and `legend` attributes, this will do what you want:

```ruby
objects.map {|obj| obj.values_at(:anonymous_user_id, :choice_index, :legend) }
  .group_by(&:shift)
```

You can skip the `map` if instead you use `pluck` in your ActiveRecord query, e.g.:

```ruby
MyModel.where(...)
  .pluck(:anonymous_user_id, :choice_index, :legend)
  .group_by(&:shift)
```

#### Edit

In reply to your comment, yes it is, although it's not quite as clean:

```ruby
MyModel.where(...)
  .pluck(:anonymous_user_id, :choice_index, :legend)
  .map {|vals| Hash[ %w[ __key__ c_idx legend ].zip(vals) ] }
  .group_by {|hsh| hsh.delete("__key__") }
```

Or:

```ruby
MyModel.where(...)
  .pluck(:anonymous_user_id, :choice_index, :legend)
  .each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(key, c_idx, legend), hsh| 
    hsh[key] << { "c_idx" => c_idx, "legend" => legend }
  end
```

Comment: Using `shift` with `group_by` is a slick way of doing that I've not seen before. Will remember this one for sure.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much! No need for me to loop in the result.

Comment: Well, in any case you're iterating over the result. You're just doing it in a smarter way (with `group_by`, and in the first case `map`).

Comment: Is it possible to result with array of hash? final_array = {
  "USER1" => [{"c_idx" => 3, "legend" => 4}, {"c_idx" => 9, "legend" => 2},{"c_idx" => 3, "legend" => 1},], 
  "USER2" => [{"c_idx" => 0, "legend" => 4}, {"c_idx" => 9, "legend" => 2},{"c_idx" => 9, "legend" => 1},],
}

Comment: Yes it is, although it's not as clean. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You can convert the output you originally wanted to the hash you mention in your comment (which you may wish to call `final_hash` :-)) with the following (among many ways of doing it), where `final_array` is your original result returned: `final_array.merge(final_array) {|*,a| a.map {|h| h.values_at("c_idx", "legend")}}`. This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the result from the query is `data_hash` (array of hash), then the following will give you the desired result:

```
data_hash = [{ 'USERNAME' => 'USER1', 'choice_indx' => 3, 'legend' => 4 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER2', 'choice_indx' => 0, 'legend' => 4 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER3', 'choice_indx' => 0, 'legend' => 4 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER1', 'choice_indx' => 9, 'legend' => 2 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER2', 'choice_indx' => 9, 'legend' => 2 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER3', 'choice_indx' => 8, 'legend' => 2 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER1', 'choice_indx' => 3, 'legend' => 1 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER2', 'choice_indx' => 9, 'legend' => 1 },
             { 'USERNAME' => 'USER3', 'choice_indx' => 8, 'legend' => 1 }]

final_array = Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}
data_hash.each do |data|
  final_array[data['USERNAME']] << [data['choice_indx'], data['legend']]
end

p final_array
# => {"USER1"=>[[3, 4], [9, 2], [3, 1]], "USER2"=>[[0, 4], [9, 2], [9, 1]], "USER3"=>[[0, 4], [8, 2], [8, 1]]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a *rails way* to do this, but with ruby you could do

```
# create hash with a empty array for each username 
results = Hash[@query.pluck(:username).map { |username| [username, []] }]
    @query.each { |data| results[data.username] << [data.choice_idx,
    data.legend] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so please accept the answer